# update rate for mouse callback

Tags: opencv, mouseevent, kalman-filter

I would like to how people handle the update rate of mouse callback. In OpenCV, according to the documentation, the [waitKey()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) is only for highGUI, therefore one can control the number of frames per second. In some applications, the location of the mouse is needed. For example, if we use the camera as the main sensory system, one can track a moving object in a video and filter that with Kalman filter. Let's say that the moving object is the mouse. If I want to use Kalman filter, the update rate of the measurement is known (i.e. `waitKey()`) but the update rate of the mouse is unknown. In this case, I have two different step sizes for the measurement and system models. The problem with mouse callback is not only unknown but it also varies. The ultimate goal of my question is to compare the actual mouse location that is provided by the operating system, the estimate of Kalman filter, and the measurement. If the experiment worked, I'm expecting the estimate to be close to the actual location while the measurement varies according to the uncertainties represented in the covariance matrix.  I will assume there is no noise in the process model that is the only noise source is the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, are you trying to synchronize Kalman's estimation and the mouse's moving? If you use Linux, you can use `nice` to give a low priority to your own program which ensures quick response to the mouse (system level). Have you run your program and does it work well? I think the update ratio should be fast enough if your system is not heavily-overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Varying observations rate is tricky, but can be handled by a Kalman filter. Your Kalman should be able to track the mouse movement, though I would add process noise just in case the movement is not according to your model.